# node tcp server stick data together

Tags: node.js, tcpserver

I am using net module in nodejs.

```
net.createServer(function(sock) {
sock.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

then I tried to use 2000 tcp clients to send data to the server to test how many clients it can support. For the first 20 minutes, it was running ok. But after a period of time, the data stuck together. For example, the data from the client is in json format and look like this:

'{"value":1,"name":"tom"}'

Each client sent the data with different name and value would be incremented each time. From the server side, the data I got look like this:

{"value":1,"name":"tom"}{"value":2,"name":"tom"}{"value":3,"name":"tom"}.

They stick together, I have to split them up and save them into mongodb.

The situation was getting worse when keep the server running longer. the server can't receive any data while the clients were still sending the data.

I'd like to ask how to make the server read one item each time and the server will work well when keep running. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The socket server doesn't know or care about your data format.  No matter what, you need to split it up.  It can be arbitrarily buffered or split before reaching your application.  The fact that you're ending up with nice segments under lower load is just due to your payload fitting into a single packet, and the app keeping up reading buffers as they come.

The easiest thing to do is use a delimiter.  Since you're using JSON, you can use a newline delimeter.  (Just make sure your JSON objects are formatted on a single line per object.)

Then, you can use a transform stream that buffers the stream, waits for a delimeter, and emits parsed objects.

Answer (score 0):

this repository can help you.The solution of sticky package problem of TCP for Node.Js

[stick](https://github.com/lvgithub/stick)

Comment: Duplicated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47667274/11644167

Answer (score -1):

[node.js stick package](https://github.com/lvgithub/stick)

You try this lib,The solution of sticky package problem of TCP for Node.Js